# How to change background and font color of td element based on a value using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie in javascript and would like to know if there is a way to highlight a table cell by changing the background color and font color if there is a particular value.

Below is the code:

```
    const testStatus = data[4].device;
    if (testStatus.count === 0) {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "NONE/UNKNOWN"
      document.getElementById('active_load').innerHTML = 'N/A';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = testStatus.Status;
      document.getElementById('active_load').innerHTML = testStatus.ActiveLoadID;
    }
```

I have many conditions like the above. How to write a function so it can change the background color to red and font color to white when there is a value like "N/A" or "None"

I tried using `document.getElementById('status').style.cssText = "background: red; color: white";`
and it did work. But i have to code a lot if i have to choose this way.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try :
```document.getElementById('status').style.backgroundColor = 'red';```

Basically you can access the same css properties in javascript except you use camelCase instead of dashes between words.

Comment: Why don't you just add a class?

Answer (score 0):

There really are few options to shrink the code, you can either access the props differently like so:

```
document.getElementById("status").style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.getElementById("status").style.color = "white";
```

If the same element is used very often you can save yourself time storing it into a variable:

```
let status = document.getElementById("status");
status.style.backgroundColor = "red";
status.style.color = "white";
// ...
```

Or, if the whole process needs to be repeated multiple times, you can take care of it with classes predefined in your (or if not present, a) css file.

```
.highlight {
  "background-color": "red";
  "color": "white";
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
// Using the variable from the second example
status.classList.add("highlight");
```

Comment: Thank you. So I will add a class in my CSS. How do I insert dynamically the 'ID's since I already have them inside the code for displaying the value using innerHTML

Comment: What do you mean specifically by inserting dynamically the ids? If you mean how to handle multiple getelementbyid's, you can freely do that without any issue, or you can do it once and reuse a variable like in my second example.

Comment: So in the HTML document, I have almost 40 id's, and each will validate like the above code and go in a table. So on your variable example,  let status = document.getElementById("status"); . If i have to do this then i will end in adding 40 variables right? So how can use this logic for each id? maybe using a function?

Comment: It really depends on how your whole code is structured, if I understand correctly it's about doing the same check on a bunch of elements, if that's the case you can just use a class, IDs are unique while classes can represent multiple elements.

Comment: So you could just give all the elements a class named status for example, then assign to a variable document.getElementsByClassName('status'). At that point you'll get a collection of all the elements with that class name, it's now up to you how to use it, you can use a for loop and adapt the code you're using now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it worked like a charm. Thanks everyone on helping me.

```
var cells = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].innerHTML == "one") {
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        cells[i].style.color = "white";
    }
}
```